# Which screen size and density should I design Android for?

Tags: android

I've been doing some reading on 4-screen sizes, and 4-densities for Android screen size suppor.  I want to get a quick prototype app up and running.  Is there any type of strategy for this or should I just (based on device size+density mostly used %'s) design for the normal screensize with med+high+xhigh dpi? Is there a best practice here?

Comment: handy link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//start design for MDPI first

```
Baseline phone  mdpi    320x480
```

from that you can increase you drawables as **1.5** for `HDPI` and **2** for `XHDPI`

TVDPI it will scale automatically by using `HDPI` assets.  `213/160 =1.33`

[Ref here:](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence)

```
 1. Use wrap_content, fill_parent, or dp units when specifying
    dimensions in an XML layout file.
 2. Do not use hard coded pixel values in your application code
 3. Do not use AbsoluteLayout (it's deprecated) 
 4. Supply alternative bitmap drawables for different screen densities
```