# Android - correct dimensions of images for multiple screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-resolution

Despite reading much of the Android developer docs on the subject, I'm still struggling with supporting multiple screen sizes/densities.  One question I have is what size my images should be.  I've read it's a good idea to start by designing images for hdpi, then copy and resize the image for ldpi, mdpi and xhdpi using the sizing ratios.  So I have an image which is 400x83 which looks great on a Nexus One/S type device (480x800) and I've resized this for the other resolution folders.  It looks fine on devices upto 5.4", but above that size (Nexus 7, Galaxy Tab etc) the image looks too small.  My question is should I actually instead be designing my images for the largest physical screen I'm supporting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12822010/1012284

Comment: That's fine if all my supported devices are the same screen size, but what about supporting multiple screen sizes between 2.7" and 10"?

Comment: there is noting with the screen sizes only you need to deal with the Density i.e XHDPI,HDPI,MDPI & LDPI. (TVDPI will scale automatically from HDPI)

Answer (score 0):

// If you are a graphics designer you need to design for XHDPI first then you need to reduce

```
75% for HDPI 
50% for MDPI
```

only you need to worry about the background

you need to supply different background for different sizes

```
1280 x 800 
480 x 320
480 x 800
1280 x 720 
1024 x 600
...
```

For that you need to put different folder like

```
drawable-hdpi
drawable-land-hdpi
drawable-land-ldpi
drawable-land-mdpi
drawable-land-xhdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-nodpi
drawable-sw600dp-hdpi
drawable-sw600dp-mdpi
drawable-sw600dp-nodpi
drawable-sw600dp-xhdpi
drawable-sw720dp-nodpi
```

[go thru this link:](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/30/designing-for-android/)